# repeating values?

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

I'm getting compiling this script which it matches all current word in the array and on the database and print if it's existing in the database.

here's the script:

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password","database");

$array=
    array(
    'quick',
    'brown',
    'fox',
    'abc123'
    );

$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT `word` FROM `table`");

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $words=$row['word'];

    foreach ($array as $value) 
    {
        if (strpos($value,$words)!== false) 
        {
            echo $value." contains a word from the database!\n<br>";
        }
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

but it keeps repeating the last element on the array.
where did I go wrong?

output:

```
quick contains a word from the database!
brown contains a word from the database!
fox contains a word from the database!
abc123 contains a word from the database!
abc123 contains a word from the database!
abc123 contains a word from the database!
abc123 contains a word from the database!
abc123 contains a word from the database!
```

Comment: What I think is happening is that you have your `echo` inside your `foreach` loop - try setting your echo outside your `foreach`

Comment: @Fred-ii- o.o how can I do that. `$value` is needed

Comment: Yeah... I thought of that after I posted.

Comment: Then try replacing `echo $value." contains a word from the database!\n<br>";` and assigning `$value` to something in its place, e.g. `$value=$found_word;` then outside the loop, do `echo $found_word." contains a word from the database!\n<br>";`

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to be possible with the script you posed. The script prints `contains a word from the database`, but your sample output doesn't have that. And the script prints `$value`, which should be entire sentences, but your sample output only contains single words.

Comment: Your latest edit still doesn't clear things up. Are you printing `$value` or `$id`? Your output is only possible if you're printing `$id`. You're making it really hard for us to help you because you're obviously not posting the actual script that's having the problem.

Comment: You can't give an array as the second argument to `strpos`. You fixed that in an earlier edit, now it's back.

Comment: I don't care about the foreach, `strpos($value, $words)` can't work because `$words` is an array.

Comment: It would help if we could see what's in your table. Since you're using `strpos`, you'll get a match for any substring of `abc123` such as `a`, `b`, `bc`, `12`, etc.

Comment: And I still don't understand why you're not getting the message `Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer`. Do you have error reporting turned off?

Comment: That link you posted doesn't show anything helpful, just some stupid animated ad.

Comment: I see you've changed the question again, now you assign `$words=...` instead of `$words[]...`. It's really not nice to keep changing the question, since the comments and answers make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change
`strpos($value,$words)!== false`

to
`preg_match('/\b'.$value.'\b/', $words)`

strpos search everything. if you search **abc123** on the database and it exist but if you also have the value of **1, 2, 3** stored in the database it will print the value that's why you have repeated value output.

Answer (score 0):

`if (strpos($value,$words)!== false)`

`$words` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
change $words[] = $row['word'];
```

to

```
$words = $row['word'];
```

Comment: run the foreach inside the while loop.

Comment: This can't be right. The whole point of that loop is to create an array of words. With this change, `$words` will just contain the last word in the table.

Comment: @Barmar yes this is correct. Cause don't need `$row['word'];` stored in the array anymore cause it gives list of all the **word**

Comment: Asker edited their question so now my answer looks silly.  Oh well, at least they removed my -1 rating...